# How do I allow Lambda to write to EFS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

The core of the issue is that if you create an EFS volume and mount point without filling out any of the group information you cannot write to it from Lambda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to create the volume and mount point with user/group ID 1000 and permissions 777.